# Proper expression to know the opening hours

Tags: word-usage

"When does your shop opens and closes?"

what would be the proper English for this expression?

Comment: What are the opening hours for....

Comment: @Josh, hair cutting salon, kebab shop, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can use the expression "What are the opening hours for..?"

Answer (score 1):

A generic question for any retail business would be:

> What are your business / operating / working / service hours?